# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() returns null on binarized Bitmap

Tags: java, android, null

I have a `byte` array with series of 0 and -1 (255). It's a result of binarization using the Otsu algorithm. I used:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = true;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; // I have tried ARGB_8888 aswell

Bitmap out = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
```

Unfortunately, it returns null. Just like the other questions regarding `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`.

I have tested other methods like nested for loops, it works but it takes too long to process, especially for large images.

This is what I currently use to generate the binarized `data`:

```
ptr = 0;
while (ptr < srcData.length)
{
    monoData[ptr] = ((0xFF & srcData[ptr]) >= threshold) ? (byte) 255 : 0;
    ptr ++;
}
```

I hope you can lead me to a better way on solving this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

565 is a representation that uses 2 bytes per pixel.

Moreover, decodeByteArray is a method that reads a *compressed* byte[] (see documentation).

Here is what I would do :

- use a int[] rather than a byte[].
- initialize like follows
- use [Bitmap.html#createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) method with the int[] resulting. The config used is not really important at this point.

`monoData[ptr] = ((0xFF & srcData[ptr]) >= threshold) ? 0xffffffff : 0xff000000;`

nota : one thing that could have helped you : decodeByteArray has no idea of the geometry of your image, hence can of course not decode it to what you are expected.

Comment: +1 but its still best to take `RGB565` where possible, as opposed to `ARGB8888` as it halves the memory size of the image. (use when alpha is not needed.)

Comment: @njzk2 Is there a reverse way where I can convert the grayscale bitmap to `int[]`? Thanks

Comment: sure, you'd be using Bitmap.getPixels, passing a properly sized int[]

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you so much! :)